# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' when working with discord for python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to write a bot message to discord without command. But I got a problem when I run the code. The error says: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/Development/Code
> Python/Bot Discord/discord-testbot.py", line 18, in my_background_task
> await channel.send(channel, 'New')
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

```py
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready')
async def my_background_task():
    
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    await channel.send(channel, 'Bot say')
client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run(tokenBot)
```

If I remove line `channel = client.get_channel(574514361394266125)`, then it raises another error, saying the name 'channel' is not defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works for me. It seems that you're calling `client.get_channel(id)` before your `client.wait_until_ready()` (you've sent the edited code so I cannot guarantee it).

This code works fine for me :

```py
async def background():
   await client.wait_until_ready()
   channel = client.get_channel(int(MY_CHANNEL))
   await channel.send("Test")

client.loop.create_task(background())
```

### Create background tasks properly :

Since the **discord.py v1.1** you can declare and manage your background task easier and safer.

This is how we do in a cog :

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

class OnReady_Message(commands.Cog):
   def __init__(self, client):
      self.client = client
      self.send_onready_message.start()

   def cog_unload(self):
      self.send_onready_message.close()
      return

   # task
   @tasks.loop(count = 1)  # do it only one time
   async def send_onready_message(self):
      channel = self.client.get_channel(int(MY_CHANNEL))
      await channel.send("Test")

   @send_onready_message.before_loop  # wait for the client before starting the task
   async def before_send(self):
      await self.client.wait_until_ready()

      return

   @send_onready_message.after_loop  # destroy the task once it's done
   async def after_send(self):
      self.send_onready_message.close()

      return
```

Finally to run the task `send_onready_message()` we can create a `Task_runner()` object or simply create in instance of the task.

### Task runner :

This will allow you run all your tasks easily :

```py
# importing the tasks
from cogs.tasks.on_ready_task import OnReady_Message

class Task_runner:
   def __init__(self, client)
      self.client = client

   def run_tasks(self):
      OnReady_Message(self.client)

      return
```

In your main file :

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from cogs.tasks.task_runner import Task_runner

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX)

runner = Task_runner(client)
runner.run_tasks()

client.run(token)
```

### Without Task_runner :

Without the `Task_runner()` we have :

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from cogs.tasks.on_ready_task import OnReady_Message

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX)

OnReady_Message(client)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

### Updating discord.py :

The example above can only work if your **discord.py** version is up to date.

To know if it is, you can run in your terminal :

```py
>>> import discord
>>> discord.__version__
'1.2.3'
```

If your version is older, you can update it by using this command in your terminal :

```
pip install discord.py --upgrade
```

Hope it helped !

Comment: I fixed in 5 second, thank you very much. Only call client.get_channel(id) after your client.wait_until_ready(). Thank so muchhhh

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to wrap my channel id with int() in the get_channel() call

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I just found this question today. I know it is already solved, but I thought I may leave my answer for future use or for other users.*

This is a solution I have just for sending direct messages (in my case):

```
# DM message
@client.command(aliases=["dm"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def _dm_(ctx, content, user_id):
    # Variables
    user = client.get_user(int(user_id))
    msg = "Sending to DM!"

    # Process
    await ctx.send(msg)
    print(msg)
    await user.send(content)
```

In this case, my issue initially was filling in `user_id` through discord as a string. Now, it takes it in as a string and then converts the ID to an integer.